# Couldn't fluentd send output in the order in which logs occur?

Tags: fluentd

`fluentd-daemonset -> fluentd-forward -> mongodb`

We are currently collecting logs using the above structure. I am collecting kubernetes container logs and storing them in mongodb.

I want to save to mongodb in order of kubernetes contaerin log time. However, there are cases where container logs that occurred a long time ago are accumulated later in mongodb.

Is this unavoidable?

Is there any way to solve this?

Is this problem caused by pos_file or buffer?